# Makefile:179: recipe for target 'obj/demo.o' failed make: *** [obj/demo.o] Error 1

Tags: python, object-detection, yolov4

When I run `!make` command in yolov4, I face the issue:

```
chmod +x *.sh
gcc -Iinclude/ -I3rdparty/stb/include -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv4 2> /dev/null || pkg-config --cflags opencv` -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -DCUDNN -Wall -Wfatal-errors -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fPIC -Ofast -DOPENCV -DGPU -DCUDNN -I/usr/local/cudnn/include -c demo.c -o obj/demo.o
demo.c:1:10: fatal error: network.h: No such file or directory
#include "network.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:179: recipe for target 'obj/demo.o' failed
make: \*\*\* \[obj/demo.o\] Error 1
```

Firstly it work fine, then I change in the `darknet/src/dectector.c` file for early save weights after 500 iteration and also change in the `cfg/yolov4-custom.cfg` file change the `max_batches` values 500500 to 500.
I don't think so it should create issue during the execution of `!make` file.

Someone have any suggestion? Anyone face this issue please guide me.

I run training command for yolov4 I face the issue access denied then I again run `!make` file at this command error came.

Comment: The error means it tried to compile something but you don't have the necessary C header files installed. Probably review the installation instructions and install all required dependencies.

Comment: Seems to be either a bug in the program you're using or an error you're causing yourself by incorrectly using it. With the little info you provide, it's impossible to give more than the generic advise you were already given. For a more specific solution, you'd have to extract a [mcve] and include that in your question, along with anything you did manually and what you actually received as output (not just paraphrasing). As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].